# Adding the openGL Particle Emitter by Michael Daley inside GLKView

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, eaglview, particle-system

I try to use the great particle emitter which Michael Daley build for his [Particle Designer](http://particledesigner.71squared.com/) to be working inside a GLKView. I see two ways to get there:

1. hack the code from his great (but too old) [tutorial](http://www.71squared.com/2009/05/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-8-particle-emitter/) to work with iOS5.1 inside a GLKView
2. pay and use his Particle Designer to add the particle effect to a glkview

I tried 1. the whole day but ended alone and lost in the wide lands of openGL. I don't know how or what is important to initialize from the GL-stuff.

I ported the classes Image, Texture2D, Common and ParticleEmitter and instantiated them  inside a GLKViewController, ending with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in line 341 of ParticleEmitter.m:

```
    // Now that all of the VBOs have been used to configure the vertices, pointer size and color
    // use glDrawArrays to draw the points
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, particleIndex);
```

and I don't know why or what....

Now I think about buying the Particle Designer and try to implement it inside the GLKViewController and its GLKView.

Is there any body who could help me with 1./2. to solve my problem, adding an openGL particle emitter to a view based application?

thanx!

edit: removed some stupid code

Comment: both, this:https://github.com/ianterrell/ExampleEngine and this:http://games.ianterrell.com/2d-game-engine-tutorial/ brought me some way further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [this one](https://github.com/71squared/GLKit_TD3D) could help a lot...
;-)

I also created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030128/ios-opengl-particle-emitter-for-glkit).