# Check iOS XCode Project Files: openGL Particle Emitter for GLKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es-2.0, eaglview, particle-system

I am trying to port the Particle Emitter by Michael Daley to GLKView and found a [XCode project where he did this on github](https://github.com/71squared/GLKit_TD3D) - unfortunately heavily bound inside a nice little game.

Now I tried to take only the particle emitter out of his game project to reuse it (I need it in 2D) and I made it up to a state without any compile error - but couldn't see nothing...

[Here is the project file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2896178/openGL_Particle_Emitter.zip). Could anybody tell me why there is no particle emitter visible?
thnx!

Comment: if you got it let me know, i'd like it !